# How to draw a rectangle in D3.js with only 2 coordinates

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am learning D3.js and will use it to draw simple lines and rectangles. My problem is, I am using data that is meant for RPG. So for a rectangle RPG only needs 2 points and it will use that diagonal line to complete the rectangle. I don't have a height or width just 2 coordinates. Is there a way to draw a rectangle in D3 using only 2 points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have two points (coordinates), the task is simple:

For the `x` and `y` position, use the first point. For the `width` and `height` of the rectangle, just calculate `x2 - x1` and `y2 - y1`, respectively.

Here is a demo with three rectangles. In the data array, each object has 4 properties, corresponding to the two points (this is just an example, you may change the code according to your data structure):

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
var data = [{x1: 20, x2: 60, y1: 30, y2: 50},
{x1: 50, x2: 80, y1: 100, y2: 150},
{x1: 200, x2: 400, y1: 10, y2: 100}];

var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", d=> d.x1)
 .attr("y", d=> d.y1)
 .attr("width", d=> d.x2 - d.x1)
 .attr("height", d=> d.y2 - d.y1)
 .attr("fill", "teal");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the same principle, but with the data containing two arrays, the first array being the first point and the second array being the second point:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
var data = [[[20,30],[40,50]], [[50,100],[80,150]], [[200,30],[400,100]]];

var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", d=> d[0][0])
 .attr("y", d=> d[0][1])
 .attr("width", d=> d[1][0] - d[0][0])
 .attr("height", d=> d[1][1] - d[0][1])
 .attr("fill", "teal");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

For both the above snippets to work, the data has to have the coordinates in this sequence: first the top-left point, then the bottom-right point. Of course, you can write a function to check this and swap the points if the order is not correct.

For drawing a diagonal, just choose the points you want. For instance, from the top-left to the bottom-right:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
var data = [{x1: 20, x2: 60, y1: 30, y2: 50},
{x1: 50, x2: 80, y1: 100, y2: 150},
{x1: 200, x2: 400, y1: 10, y2: 100}];

var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", d=> d.x1)
 .attr("y", d=> d.y1)
 .attr("width", d=> d.x2 - d.x1)
 .attr("height", d=> d.y2 - d.y1)
 .attr("fill", "teal")
 .attr("opacity", 0.3);
  
var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("line")
 .attr("x1", d=> d.x1)
 .attr("y1", d=> d.y1)
 .attr("x2", d=> d.x2)
 .attr("y2", d=> d.y2)
 .attr("stroke", "firebrick")
 .attr("stroke-width", 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to draw from bottom left corner

Comment: I suggest you posting a proper question.